# Prestashop user's phone number

Tags: php, database, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I would like to ask where is saved user's phone and address in prestashop database? 
I tried search in customer table but there are only basic informations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a question that could use the version of Prestashop you are using.

According to the technical database documentation of the version 1.5, it's stored in the table ps_address.

[Documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Fundamentals#Fundamentals-Databaseschema)

Answer (score 0):

please check ps_address table all the address related information have saved in prestashop 1.6